# Convert int value to decimal value in xslt1.0

Tags: xslt, number-formatting

How to convert an integer value to a decimal value in XSLT?

For example, convert

```
15954 to 159.54

12376 to 123.76

22090 to 220.90
```

I used the `format-number` function, but it does not give the intended result.

```
format-number(22090,'#.##')
```

Comment: How would you convert `15954` to `159.54` in another programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd clearly need to divide the number by 100 before formatting it, but also you need to use 0 rather than # after the decimal point to force 2dp.

```
format-number(theNumber div 100,'#.00')
```